# neo4j: error "TM encountered an unexpected error condition" when create node

Tags: neo4j

I try create node in neo4j plugin, but I have error "TM encountered an unexpected error condition".

Where is my mistake?

This is the stacktrace:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager$ResourceHolder.enlist(PersistenceManager.java:412)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager$ResourceHolder.forWriting(PersistenceManager.java:394) 
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.ensureWriteTransaction(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:190) 
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.upgradeToDataTransaction(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:220) 
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelStatement.dataWriteOperations(KernelStatement.java:83)
org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.createNode(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1110)
ru.a360.neo4j.plugins.UtilsUpdateTimetable.createTrain(UtilsUpdateTimetable.java:162) 
ru.a360.neo4j.plugins.Utils.updateOrCreateTrain(Utils.java:1848) 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61) 
org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:159) 
org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312) 
org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) 
org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469) 
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349) 
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339) 
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) 
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698) 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:211) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096) 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268) 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229) 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358) 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601) 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There is stack trace in aswer, sorry)

Comment: can you be more specific about what you are trying? Do you have a sample code? What version of Neo4j are you using etc?

Comment: which version of Neo4j are you using? Did you register any custom components like kernel extensions or transaction event handlers? Share the code from 'your' part of the stacktrace (UtilsUpdateTimetable, Utils).

Comment: There is two functions code: http://www.codeshare.io/1VQTB

Comment: I use neo4j 2.1.3 and I didn't register any custom components.